# Keyboard focus on gallery controls

Tags: jquery, tabindex, fancybox-3

I'm using Fancybox for a large gallery and I can't seem to figure out the correct way to use tabindex to focus on the individual gallery controls, for keyboard navigation.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      $("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
        baseTpl : '<div class="fancybox-container" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">' +
                    '<div class="fancybox-bg"></div>' +
                    '<div class="fancybox-caption-wrap" style="top:0;padding-top:15px;background:none;">' +
                      '<div class="fancybox-caption" style="border:0;"></div>' +
                    '</div><button class="fancybox-button fancybox-button--left" data-fancybox-previous="" style="top:45%;left:0 !important;z-index:9999999;" title="Previous" tabindex="1"></button>' +
                    '<div class="fancybox-controls" style="bottom:0;top:auto;">' +
                      '<div class="fancybox-infobar" style="width:100%;">' +
                        '<div class="fancybox-infobar__body" style="background:transparent;">' +
                          '<span class="js-fancybox-index"></span>&nbsp;/&nbsp;<span class="js-fancybox-count"></span>' +
                        '</div>' +
                      '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="fancybox-controls">' +
                      '<div class="fancybox-buttons">' +
                        '<button class="fancybox-button fancybox-button--close" data-fancybox-close="" title="Close (Esc)" tabindex="1"></button>' +
                      '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="fancybox-slider-wrap">' +
                      '<div class="fancybox-slider"></div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<button class="fancybox-button fancybox-button--right" data-fancybox-next="" style="top:45%;right:0 !important;z-index:9999999;position:fixed;" title="Next" tabindex="1"></button>' +
                  '</div>'
      });
    });
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I've attached tabindex="1" to every node and tested it that way - all I seem to get when I tab in the browser is a focus on the caption, but none of the controls (buttons, etc).

http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/

Comment: While you can press tab to change focus on navigation buttons - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ybjveO (I have addded red outline to better see active element) - the problem is that prev/next buttons lose focus after image change.

Comment: @Janis thank you, but I'm looking for default browser focus, not CSS-based. Your solution works for what it is, however.

Comment: Are you aware that you can simply style (using CSS) an element when it gets focus?